# Syrian Passport and visa validity -- Travel to Canada

Tags: visas, passport-renewals

I have Syrian passport. It is valid until 19 Sep, 2019.

And my visa is also valid until 19 Sep, 2019.

I am planning to travel to Canada on 21 May 2019 and return on 10 June 2019.

Can I make this trip?

Comment: What is your specific concern?

Answer (score 2):

Canada requires that your passport be [valid for the period authorized for your stay](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-2002-227/page-12.html?txthl=passport#s-52). Canada does not have a "six month rule" for passport validity (or three months or any number of months) as some other countries do.

Because of this regulation, Canada Border Services Agency officers will generally give you a [six month entry](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/visa-validity-expiry-dates.html), or entry until the date of expiration of your passport, whichever is shorter.

You will have no problem with the period of stay, because you will depart before your passport expires.

Answer (score 0):

Canada requires your passport be valid for 3 months after your expected departure. [Non-official site -Scroll to exceptions.](https://fastportpassport.com/blog/six-month-validity-passport-rule)

Seeing as you have a visa, and a passport that expire 3 months and 9 days after your expected departure, then you should be fine.  However, it would be prudent to check with your nearest Canadian Consulate.

Comment: AFAIK the unofficial site you linked to is wrong, and Canada only requires passports to be valid during your visit. This is what Timatic says. It's also probably why Canada synchronizes visa expiration dates to the passport expiration date.

Comment: Aha, found it in the [immigration regulations](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-2002-227/page-12.html?txthl=passport#s-52).

Comment: @michaelHampton  That looks like the rules for those landing as permanent residents.

Comment: It specifically says _temporary residents_, not permanent residents. Which is Canada's legal classification for all visitors (tourist, business, transit, students, etc).